# Dynamic sql to populate a stored procedure variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to add a record in a `aTable` using a stored procedure. But before that I need to check if it's a duplicate entry. If its not duplicate then only add to `aTable`.

I have one stored procedure that does two things

1. checking for duplicate
2. and if not duplicate then only add the record.

In this stored procedure, I have

1. `@count` variable (scope is the stored procedure itself)
2. column values as parameters (7-8  as  `varchar` datatype)

I am setting `@count` to `1` and then building the dynamic `@qry` string that will hold the `@count` value as follows using `@column` values

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_aTable_ADD
   @col1 varchar(20) = null,
   @col2 varchar(20) = null,
   @col3 varchar(20) = null,
   ...
   @colN varchar(20) = null,
AS
   DECLARE @count int
   SET @count = 1

   DECLARE @qry nvarchar(max)
   SET @qry = 'SELECT @count = count(*) FROM aTable WHERE '

   IF @col1 IS NOT EMPTY
   BEGIN
       SET @qry = @qry + ' col1 = '+ ''''+@col1+''''
   END

   IF @col2 IS NOT EMPTY
   BEGIN
       SET @qry = @qry + ' AND col2 = '+ ''''+@col2+''''
   END

   ...
   ...

   IF @colN IS NOT EMPTY
   BEGIN
       SET @qry = @qry + ' colN = '+ ''''+@colN+''''
   END

   /*once all the stored procedure variables are done processing, close the sql*/
   SET @qry = @qry + ' )'

   /*final @qry value would end up looking like as follows
   SELECT @count = count(*) 
   FROM aTable 
   WHERE (col1 = 'val1' AND col2 = 'val2' AND col3 = 'val3')*/
```

Now, within this stored procedure I want to know the value of `@count` and if it is '0' then continue with the 'INSERT' procedure. I am stuck at getting '@count' value within this stored procedure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Assuming this is for **SQL Server**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: This is just for illustration, i am using my own prefixes. But thats for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use dynamic sql for this just Write a query with a WHERE Clause something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_aTable_ADD  --<-- Use usp
   @col1 varchar(20) = null,
   @col2 varchar(20) = null,
   @col3 varchar(20) = null,
   ...
   @colN varchar(20) = null,
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Count INT;

SELECT @count = count(*) 
FROM aTable 
WHERE 
     (@col1 IS NULL OR Col1 = @col1)
AND  (@col2 IS NULL OR Col2 = @col2)
AND  (@col3 IS NULL OR Col3 = @col3)
.
.
AND  (@colN IS NULL OR ColN = @colN)

--And then at the end of your Proc just return the @Count Variable 

   RETURN @count;
END
```

Comment: I think the main reason for doing this with dynamic is that all these conditions result in very poor performance due to the cardinality of the where clause. If there is an index on Col1 for example and this is the only parameter with a value, the query will not use the index on `col1`. Since all columns are in the where clause this will always result in a full table scan, even if it not the actually the best query plan.

Comment: @GarethD `(@col1 IS NULL OR Col1 = @col1)` in this case if the parameter @col1 is null it will not even bother looking at other condition at all, or will it ??

Comment: Only if you use `OPTION (RECOMPILE);` at the end of your query. At compile time the query has no knowledge of what the value of the parameters will be, so cannot optimize away the redundant clauses. Obviously if you force recompilation of the query once the parameters are known then it can optmise them away, it really depends on whether the complexity of the query, and the frequency of execution as to whether the added cost of recompilation for each execution will be significant or not.

Comment: Also, not really relevant to the question, but it's generally advised that you should not use `RETURN` to send data out of a stored procedure, this is what output parameters are for. The return value is generally used to return execution status.

Answer (score 0):

Use an output parameter:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry, N'@Count INT OUTPUT', @Count OUTPUT;
```

For a simple test:

```
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT @Count = 10';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry, N'@Count INT OUTPUT', @Count OUTPUT;
SELECT @Count;
```

Finally, you never open the parentheses in your WHERE Clause:

```
SET @qry = 'SELECT @count = count(*) FROM aTable WHERE '
```

But you go on to close them:

```
SET @qry = @qry + ' )'
```

Also, if all your parameters are null even if you did open the parentheses you will get an incorrect syntax error since your SQL will be:

```
SELECT @count = count(*) FROM aTable WHERE ();
```

Or if @Col1 is NULL You will get:

```
SELECT @count = count(*) FROM aTable WHERE AND col2 = col2();
```

You can avoid this by firstly removing the parenthesis. `WHERE A = 1` means exactly the same as `WHERE (A = 1)`, and by adding a meaningless where first:

```
SET @qry = 'SELECT @count = count(*) FROM aTable 1 = 1 ';

IF @col1 IS NOT EMPTY
BEGIN
    SET @qry = @qry + ' AND col1 = '+ ''''+@col1+''''
END
```

Finally I would recommend further parameterising your query.

```
SET @qry = 'SELECT @count = count(*) FROM aTable WHERE 1 = 1 '
DECLARE @ParamDef NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@Col1 VARCHAR(20), @Col2 VARCHAR(20), @Col3 VARCHAR(20), @Count INT OUTPUT';

IF @Col1 IS NOT NULL
    SET @qry = @qry + ' AND Col1 = @Col1';

IF @Col2 IS NOT NULL
    SET @qry = @qry + ' AND Col2 = @Col2';

IF @Col3 IS NOT NULL
    SET @qry = @qry + ' AND Col3 = @Col3';


EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry, @ParamDef, @Col1, @Col2, @Col3, @Count OUTPUT;
```

**[Working Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b37b/2)**

Comment: `Constrcutive Criticisim: ` I too thought of this method 1st but if a variable is NULL and you do not concatenate it to query string , when passing parameters to sp_executesql you will be passing all the parameter which were concatinated to sql query string and which werent. Can lead to possible issues. A simple query with the WHERE clause shown in my answer keeps things short simple and sweet :)

Comment: In that instance it will just be ignored, it is no different to doing something like `DECLARE @A INT = 1; SELECT 0;` @A is declared but never used, it does not affect the query, and also the cost of declaring a variable is minimal. With regard to the simple query in your answer see my comment below about sub optimal execution plans due to the cardinality of the where clause. (SQL Fiddle appears to be temporarily down, so I can't yet share the example I have done to demonstrate this).